# Type mismatch when returning from inside if statement

Tags: rust, type-mismatch

The following code fails to compile:

```
fn testing() -> i32 {
    let x = 5;
    if x == 5 {
        5
    }
    6
}
```

with this error:

```
error E0308: mismatched types. (expected (), found integral variable)
```

If I put an explicit `return` in front of the `5`, or if I put the `6` inside an `else` block, everything works fine. What exactly is Rust complaining about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rust, nearly everything is an expression, including `if`-`else`. `if` generates a value, but there is no value for the expression if the expression fails (i.e. `x != 5`). When putting the `6` into the else block, the `if`-`else` statement returns an integral (which will be an `i32` due to the return type). You can suppress the statement's value with a semicolon.

`return 5` (note, that there is no semicolon) is also a statement, which results in `()`. Now the `if` expression always returns `()`, which is fine.

Idiomatically you should prefer the `else` variant, so you can omit the `return`:

```
fn testing() -> i32 {
    let x = 5;
    if x == 5 {
        5
    } else {
        6
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`if-else` is an assignable expression that has a type. Omitting `else {}` is equivalent to `if { ... } else { () }`. If you assign that value to a variable:

```
// would not compile
let result = if x == 5 {
    5
};
```

it is equivalent to writing:

```
let result = if x == 5 {
    5
} else {
    ()
};
```

Making the type of `result` either integer or unit, which is invalid.